# Google Map circles are seems like hand drawn image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Google Maps circle looks like hand drawn.

Circle script is:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({

    center: myLatLng,
    radius:1000,
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity:1,
    fillOpacity:0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#000000",
    map:map
});
```

Can we make the circle more fine tuned.

[image]

My requirement is to show circle around marker with fine tuned circle border.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'hand drawn' and 'fine tuned'?

Comment: @Yaniv see the circle border in the attached image. It seems like a hand drawn image. I want smooth border  for circle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a symbol. I don't believe there's an option to change those circles from using the "hand-drawn" style. It's odd because their rectangles don't seem to be using that look.

Here is an example :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined

```
function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

      var myCircle = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        scale: 20,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWeight: 3
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        icon: myCircle,
        map: map
      });
    }
```

Here is an example of a circle around a marker :

```
    function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(16.5083,80.64);var mapOptions = {zoom: 12,center: myLatlng};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: myLatlng});

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 2000,
      fillColor: '#000000',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: My requirement is to show circle around marker with fine tuned circle border. Your suggestion works to show circle as marker image.

Comment: Here I have to show marker image inside circle and circle border should be fine tuned when compared to the attached image. Your solution is to show a circle image instead of marker image in the circle.

Comment: how do you calculate the radius in this case? e.g. imagine i would like to show 10 km radius?